# Screen issue on Asus Transformer Prime TF201?

Tags: screen, asus-eee-pad-transformer

Sometimes when using the Asus Transformer Prime TF201, I see some artifacts or static occuring along the left side of the screen as pictured below. It kind of looks like a white barcode. It is running the latest version of Android 4.0.3 the **"Asus Eee Pad Transformer Prime TF201 Firmware: V9.4.2.28"** this tablet has not been unlocked, yet...

[image: Asus Transformer Prime TF201 screen distortion]
<sup>Asus Transformer Prime TF201 screen distortion (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Happens most often when viewing web pages in Chrome, etc. It does not happen all the time. Any ideas what might be causing this? Software, hardware, anyone else ever seen anything like this?

Is this a hardware aka warranty issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen  this on occasion on mine.  It seems to be a software issue, triggered by certain usage patterns.   [This post on XDA-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1504786) has some info on how you may be able to trigger it.   That community seems to be hoping that the 4.1 Jelly Bean update will include a cure.

Comment: Have not been able to reproduce the effect since posting the question, even after following the steps noted.

Comment: This does kind of lean towards the side that its just a software issue, Phew!!!